# Magento Add product to cart by Session ID/Visitor ID

Tags: php, magento, session, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I am running a script outside my Magento, here i will have Session ID/Visitor ID and also i have Product ID, Qty.

By Session ID/Visitor ID i can get the Customer ID if the customer is loggedin & also able to add product to cart.

```
$product_id = 123; // Product ID
$qty = 1; // Qty
$storeId = 1; // Store ID
$customer_id = 1; // Customer ID
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($storeId)->loadByCustomer($customer_id);
                $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
                $quote->setIsActive(1);
                $quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Now my question is

If the customer is Guest customer then how can i add the product to his/her cart ?

Any idea ?

Comment: You can't, guest don't have sessions as far as I know.

Comment: @JulienLachal Using this i am able to get session id $sessionId = Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getEncryptedSessionId();